# How do i get the button's color to change?

Tags: xml, android-studio, button

Here's my button in a fragment

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="login"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".7"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"/>
```

And here's the applied background for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<solid android:color="#F82F5A"/>
</shape>
```

[image: The button]

The button remains unchanged

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside the Button tag :

`android:background="<hex color>"`

or:

`android:backgroundTint="<hex color>"`

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't working either

Comment: Try changing theme to App Compat in Styles.xml or Themes.xml